# split a boolean expression by the outermost AND operators

Tags: python, boolean, expression

In python how can I split a boolean expression containing AND, OR clauses by the AND operator in lesser lines of code. is there some function or module to support these kind of operations?

eg. if the expression is --
       ((a AND b) OR (c AND d)) AND (d OR a)
i just want to split it by the outer most AND's ie
       {((a AND b) OR (c AND d)), (d OR a)}

PS - the AND and OR are python operators, not strings.

Comment: What exactly is your purpose in splitting them? Do you want to take a string representation of the statement and split it? Do you want to find the truth values of the top level statements separated by 'and' separately? Why do you have to separate these programmatically rather than manually?

Comment: I have a program that creates random large boolean expressions. And I would like to get an idea of how "true" a given expression is. I chose to do so by breaking it into clauses separated by AND and checking how many such clauses are true for a given expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean something like

```
>>> some_operation((a and b) and c)
(a and b), c
```

then you can't.  The expression is evaluated before any function could be called, and there is no syntax to do this in python.  I'm not really sure why you'd want to.

If this is not what you mean, then please explain.